# Proving $c_1(L \otimes L') = c_1(L) + c_1(L')$ for line bundles.

Tags: differential-geometry, characteristic-classes

I'm trying to prove this seemingly innocent result that for line bundles $L $and $L'$ the Chern class of the tensor product bundle is given by $$c_1(L \otimes L') = c_1(L) + c_1(L').$$

I managed to find this proven in few places, but all of the proofs are done in a quite a different framework compared to the one I'm working in.

I've defined $c_k(E) = \left[f_k\left(\frac{i}{2\pi}\Omega\right)\right]$ where $\Omega$ is the curvature matrix and $f_k$ the k'th elementary symmetric polynomial.

Bott and Tu does this using the Euler class for which they have the expression $$e(E)=-\frac{1}{2\pi i} \sum_\gamma d(\rho_\gamma d\log g_{\gamma \alpha})$$ and use the cocycle on the product bundle $L \otimes L'$ to conclude, but I would like to have a more direct way instead of deriving this expression $e(E)=-\frac{1}{2\pi i} \sum_\gamma d(\rho_\gamma d\log g_{\gamma \alpha})$ for the Euler class. Is this doable? I didn't find at least any easy way to proceed.

Comment: Have you written down the obvious connection on the tensor product, given connections on the line bundles? What is its curvature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(E,\nabla)$ be a vector bundle with a flat connection, i.e., $\nabla\colon \mathfrak X(M)\times\Gamma(E)\to \Gamma(E)$. Now the tensor product of $(E_1,\nabla_1)$ and $(E_2,\nabla_2)$ is $(E_1\otimes E_2,\nabla_1\otimes1+1\otimes\nabla_2)$, i.e., with the connection (for $s_i\in\Gamma(E_i)$)
$$\nabla_X(s_1\otimes s_2)=\nabla_Xs_1\otimes s_2+s_1\otimes\nabla_Xs_2.$$
Now given $(E,\nabla)$, the curvature $R_E$ is, for $X,Y\in\mathfrak X(M)$,
$$R_E(X,Y):=[\nabla_X,\nabla_Y]-\nabla_{[X,Y]}\colon \Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(E).$$
Now,
$$\begin{align*}
R_{E_1\otimes E_2}(X,Y)&=[\nabla_X\otimes1+1\otimes\nabla_X,\nabla_Y\otimes1+1\otimes\nabla_Y]-(\nabla_{[X,Y]}\otimes1+1\otimes\nabla_{[X,Y]})\\
&=[\nabla_X,\nabla_Y]\otimes1+1\otimes[\nabla_X,\nabla_Y]-(\nabla_{[X,Y]}\otimes1+1\otimes\nabla_{[X,Y]})\\
&=R_{E_1}(X,Y)\otimes1+1\otimes R_{E_2}(X,Y).
\end{align*}$$
Thus, upon taking traces (recall that $c_1(E)=\frac{i}{2\pi}\mathrm{tr}\ \Omega_E$ where $\Omega_E$ is the matrix representing $R_E$), we obtain
$$\Omega_{E_1\otimes E_2}(X,Y)=r_2\Omega_{E_1}(X,Y)+r_1\Omega_{E_2}(X,Y),$$
where $r_i$ is the rank of $E_i$, so passing to cohomology,
$$c_1(E_1\otimes E_2)=r_2c_1(E_1)+r_1c_1(E_2).$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on where do the ranks $r_1$ and $r_2$ appear for $\Omega_{E_1\otimes E_2}(X,Y)=r_2\Omega_{E_1}(X,Y)+r_1\Omega_{E_2}(X,Y)$? @kenta-s

Comment: In general given a $r_1$-dimensional vector space $V_1$ and a $r_2$-dimensional vector space $V_2$, and endomorphisms $\alpha_i$ of $V_i$, we have $\mathrm{tr}\ (\alpha_1\otimes1+1\otimes\alpha_2)=r_2\mathrm{tr}\ \alpha_1+r_1\mathrm{tr}\ \alpha_2$.

Comment: I see, thank you. Do you need the assumption that the connection is flat? I don't think you used it in the proof? @kenta-s

Comment: @Tepes yes, that is my bad, flatness is not used in the proof.